# Get a higher resolution png from a favicon resource

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, favicon, ico

I'm currently trying to display external sites' favicons on my site and I've noticed that unfortunately if I have a tag in my HTML `<img src="https://example.com/favicon.ico">` then the image that is displayed on the page is the lowest resolution image stored in the .ico file. I was wondering if there was a simple way to specify that I want the highest quality image. This method is a fallback for when sites don't have a `<link rel="icon" ... />` tag and I do know that I can use a library to read the .ico file but I just wanted to check if there was a quick and dirty solution. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at SVG for fav - https://css-tricks.com/svg-favicons-and-all-the-fun-things-we-can-do-with-them/

Comment: I don't believe this is relevant? I'm asking about the case where a site doesn't specify a location for a favicon (SVG or otherwise) and thus extracting data from the .ico

Comment: Apart from just guessing where a dev would place higher res icons (and by default they would be at the root), I see no viable path to doing this. Since `.ico` files are usually a 16x16 image, I also don't think you will get a higher resolution image out of that even if you could parse it with a script (which, well, you can't). I don't think there's a quick and dirty solution available, best to crawl and look for things like `app-icon` and `favicon` meta tags...

Comment: .ico files actually often hold multiple images. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)

Comment: And libraries exist https://github.com/egy186/icojs. But I wanted to just do it without any data parsing from the file by the client as it saves me from sending the file to the client (I can just send a url), which is necessary due to CORS. And yes, I look at all possible tags before looking for the .ico file, however some sites like https://google.com/ don't have any tags.